# Emberjs with Jquery mobile changing URL

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js

I wanted to use jQuery Mobile for an app with Ember framework, but it seems that jquery mobile is modifying the URL of ember ?

For example, I have this basic url from ember :

=> `localhost/Marco/Dev/Project1/#/home`

It will automatically modify the url like that :

=> `localhost/home`

and this is causing me some issue with a lot of thing, and I was wondering if it was possible to disable this thing on Jquery mobile ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery mobile custom builder and uncheck all related to url based components like Navigate in events etc.

http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/